# How to append data from one dataset to main dataset using SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

SSRS based question:
I have data coming from 2 different sources ( SQL Server and Oracle ) they have same fields and I have created 2 datasets for each, here SQL has the old data say 2 Yrs back and Oracle has the latest data. So my question is how can I append old SQL data with new Oracle data and show that in one tablix

1. Tried using parameters but not working for me, I might be doing it in wrong way

Expected result would be to append the 2 dataset results into one so that I can put that into one tablix

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data and include any key columns. If you have a column that makes each row unique across the 2 datasets (maybe a period id for similar) then there is a way to do it. Let me know and I'll post a full answer if required

Comment: @AlanSchofield - There is no key column as such, just I have same raw data and need to combine it issue being it is coming from 2 different data sources. Also after combining I need to apply aggregate function (SUM) to it as need to get the sum of Tax amount for particular vendor

Comment: If you can generate some unique IDs in the dataset query then you can still use this technique. If you where using SQL Server you could do use ROW_NUMBER in your first dataset and ROW_NUMBER + 100 (or some number bigger than your expected row count in dataset 1) for you 2nd dataset. You can follow the link I posted to my other answer and just make sure the number table you generate is large enough to cover both tables.If you can;t follow it, post and example of your datasets

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment,
You could achieve this with the help of Subreports. Why subreports basically tabllix in SSRS will show data from one data set. But you could have something like data from dataset Oracle where each rows has few column and let’s consider it has unique field let’s call it accountid  and based on acoountid, if you have rows from dataset sql you could show row in subreport from another dataset sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to append similar data from one dataset to another, you can place a second table right underneath the first table.

- Copy the first table
- Paste a copy of the table right under the first table
- Delete the header of the second table
- Change the location of the table so it butts up to the first table
  (if you table has a header and data row heights of .25 inches, the
  second table would start at .5 inches [top location] )
- Change the dataset of the second table to your second dataset,
  changing fields if needed

The result will look like one table though it's really two. It should be unnoticeable when exporting to excel. As long as there is no gap between the first and second tables, there won't be an extra blank row between the data.

Comment: Thanks. will try your solution. Also after fetching the data I have an expression which will aggregate the data

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to combine the datasets into one so you can use them in charts etc then I came up with a method a few days ago when working out an answer for another question.

You should be able to use the same principle on your data.

If this does not work, then please post a sample of your data including key/unique column(s) and I'll add a full answer based on your scenario.

Take a look at my answer to a similar problem here first..

[Is there a way to get list of all column values from multiple datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640831/is-there-a-way-to-get-list-of-all-column-values-from-multiple-datasets/55641987#55641987)